# How to change private @mobx.observable.ref mobx state via props?

Tags: typescript, mobx

Currently my class is defined this way:

```
type ClapWidgetProps = {
  animate: boolean,

};

export class Widget extends React.Component<WidgetProps> {
  @mobx.observable.ref private animate: boolean = this.props.animate || false;
```

This observable `animate` controls some animation effect inside the widget.

As you can see the internal state `animate` is initialised by `this.props.animate`.

What I want to achieve is that I wish to able to change the value of the observable `animate` via `this.props.animate` continuously even after initialisation.

How can I let `this.props.animate` override observable `animate` when the property is changed?

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to control animation both from inside and from outside component you need to benefit from the React lifecycle methods

```
@observer
export class Widget extends React.Component<WidgetProps> {
  @observable private animate: boolean = this.props.animate || false;

  toggleAnimate = () => {
    this.animate = !this.animate;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.animate !== this.props.animate) {
      this.animate = this.props.animate;
    }
  }

  render() {
     // call  this.toggleAnimate to change animate from inside component
  }
}
```

And from outer

```
// some jsx

<Widget animate={this.state.animate} />

// and if outer component this.state.animate changes - it will cause a change of Widget animate prop
```

Answer (score 1):

MobX is all about  the `stores` which are state of your application. In your example you have 2 sources of animate property which (within your `Widget` component and somewhere outside which you pass to `Widget` as `prop`) isn't really a good practice.

This would be a much better way to setup your application

```
class Store {
    @observable animate = false;

    @action
    setAnimate(animate) {
        this.animate = animate;
    }
}

@inject('store')
class Widget extends React.Component {
    toggleAnimate = () => {
        const { store } = this.props;
        store.setAnimate(!store.animate);
    }

    render() {
        const { animate } = this.props.store;
        // whenever animate changes in your store render method will trigger
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not working example since you'll have to setup your `Provider` at root level of your application. Please see section `Provider and inject` https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react for more info.

You can find more about defining stores at https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html.